# Configure Bamboo to call SonarQube to analyze Servlet Based Java Application

Tags: sonarqube, bamboo

We have one old Servlet based application and we use bamboo for continuous integration and build. Is there any way to call sonarqube to analyze the code. There is one Sonar For Bamboo plug in but that's not for free.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it. The plugin just let you configure the Sonar steps in a more friendly way and put the configurations about the SonarQube server in the plugin configuration.
What you can do is to install in the Bamboo server (or where the agents are running) the SonarClient for the technology that you want to analyze. And you just need to configure in the properties of that client, the url and credentials of the SonarQube server.
Even you can do this last thing directly when you are running the analyze, using the client parameters.